# ansible playbook role variable

Tags: ansible

fairly new to ansible.
having following role e.g.: `my-role` - i have trouble overriding the default variables from the playbook

follwing files:

```
my-role/tasks/main.yml
my-role/defaults/main.yml
sample-playbook.yml
```

my-role/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: "Add Test User"
  user: name={{ my_config_test_user }} comment="{{ my_config_test_user }}" group={{ my_config_test_user }}
```

my-role/defaults/main.yml

```
my_config_test_user: "test"
```

playbook:

```
- name: TestCase
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    my_config_test_user: "override"
  roles:
    - my-role
```

in the task the value of `my_config_test_user` stays `test` instead of my expected result `override`

any hints?

regards

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the current version of Ansible order of precedence says that the value of `my_config_test_user` should be *override* not *test* so I think you probably have a typo somewhere.  Maybe the variable is not spelled correctly?

I suggest removing defaults/main.yml temporarily to ensure that you do not get an undefined variable error. I would also suggest using the debug module to check the value of the variable in your tasks/main.yml

```
- debug: var={{ my_config_test_user }}
```

For reference here is the order of precedence (starting with the greatest) in the current version of Ansible:

1. Vars set on the command line -e foo=set_on_cmd_line
2. Vars set in the vars_files: block in the play
3. Vars set in the vars: block in the play
4. Vars set in host_vars/
5. Vars set in group_vars/
6. Role default vars roles/.../defaults/main.yml

Comment: many thx!!! it was a typo and moving away the defaults files showed it :)
many many thx - it freaked me out - i read the whole documentation and so on also +1 for your variable precedence listing!!